# MySQL and joins

Tags: mysql, join

I'm struggling with MySQL right now. Basically, I have three tables:

- comments (id, thread_id, ...)
- threads (id, forum_id, ...)
- forums (id, ...)

And this is what I came up with to select all threads from a particular forum:

```
SELECT * FROM threads WHERE forum_id IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM threads
    WHERE id = 4
)
```

Now, what I don't understand is how to select all comments from a particular forum.

Can't be that hard?!!

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select comments.* 
 from forums
 left join threads
 on threads.forum_id = forums.id and forums.id = 4
 left join comments 
 on threads.id = comments.thread_id
 ;
```

After reading the question I think the Bob wants all the comments from the forum with id 4. Not sure I am correct.

Comment: Mr. Radical, that's exactly what I was aiming at. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select * from threads 
 inner join forums
 on forums.id = threads.forum_id
 inner join comments
 on comments.thread_id = threads.id
 where threads.id = 4
```

Comment: Or perhaps he means "where forums.id = 4". His original query, although it *says* it's pulling all threads.id = 4, may actually want all forums.id = 4, since he said he wanted to pull all threads from a particular forum. I don't think it's totally clear from his question.

Comment: @Melanie he didnt give any example , just his thinking and the query.

Comment: Melanie and echo_me: Sorry for not including any examples. Mr. Radical helped me out.